# Qt Creator не видит компиляторы

Tags: c++, qtcreator

При попытке отладить консольное приложение выдаёт:

> -1: ошибка: Необходимо в настройках комплекта задать компилятор для сборки.

Захожу инструменты>Параметры, и во вкладке компиляторы нет ни одного компилятора. Что делать? 
[image: Нету компиляторов]

Comment: Добавить компилятор)

Comment: @PavelParshin т.е. компилятор надо ручками ставить?

Comment: Только при попытке отладки такое? Просто собрать приложение получается?

Comment: @Алексей Qt Creator не смог найти в стандартных каталогах компилятор. Соответственно надо установить его и при необходимости указать где он находится.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ - переустановить QT, во время установки выбрать компиляторы - (там будет список какие компоненты установить) - выберите MinGV или MSVC. Данный выбор всех компонент доступен только в он-лайн инсталяторе.